# Suppose $P(x,y,z)$ and $Q(x,y,z)$ have continuous partial derivatives on $\mathbb{R}^3$,

Tags: calculus

Suppose $P(x,y,z)$ and $Q(x,y,z)$ have continuous partial derivatives on $\mathbb{R}^3$, and for every smooth surface $\Sigma$, it holds $$\iint_{\Sigma}P \, \mathrm{d}y \, \mathrm{d}z + Q \, \mathrm{d}z \, \mathrm{d}x=0$$
Prove $$\frac{\partial P}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial Q}{\partial y}=0$$.
This form looks like Gauss' Theorem, except the surface maybe not close. Wondering I could do it from Gauss' Theorem's proof. But still no clues.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\vec{F} = P \hat{x} + Q \hat{y}$ and take a region $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^2.$ You can then apply Gauss Theorem on $\Omega \times [z_1, z_2].$ The volume and surface integrals can be written in terms of area and curve integrals in the $xy$-plane.

Comment: And how to connect  $\Omega \times [z_1, z_2].$ to the surface $\Sigma$, It may not be close.

Comment: Let $\Sigma := \partial(\Omega \times [z_1, z_2]).$ That is closed.

Comment: But $\Sigma$ is artbitrary

Comment: You are not going to show that something is valid for every $\Sigma.$ What you are given is that if you have a surface $\Sigma$ then you know that a specific integral over that surface vanishes. You are allowed to apply the statement to any smooth surface of your choice. It just as if you were given a function $f$ with some specific property; you can apply the function to any element of your choice as long as that element is in the domain of $f$.